# Serenity with Cucumber and Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I am using Springboot with Serenity as the UI Test Framework and I want to add cucumber to my project. 
My Problem is, that the Test will not boot my Springboot testapplication. Can you please help me?
My dependencies:

```
testCompile("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityVersion}")
testCompile("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:${serenityVersion}")
testCompile("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-spring:${serenityVersion}")
testCompile("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${cucumberVersion}")

testCompile("info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5")
```

My Serenity/Cucumber test (FrontendTestApplication is annotated with @SpringbootApplication):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = {FrontendTestApplication.class})
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
public class InputStationCucumber {
}
```

If I run my old Test, everthing is working fine, but this test doesn't start my Springboot app.

Can you guys help me?

Regards,
Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.
You have to annotate the steps defining class with `@SpringBootTest`, not the runner class.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: as per working or not, this is working, when I transfer the annotation to step definition it started working, but how much authentic it is I don't know :)